# ddply in r - how to refer to variables by column index

Tags: r, plyr

Suppose I have a data frame with many columns and a particular summary procedure that I wish to apply. There may be several columns I am interested in summarizing by, e.g. columns 2, 3 and 4 of the `baseball` dataset:

```
   ddply(baseball, .(year), "nrow")
   ddply(baseball, .(stint), "nrow")
   ddply(baseball, .(team), "nrow")
```

Of course I may wish to apply a more complicated summary and have more columns of output, but let's stick with the assumption that the summary is going to be done by a single column, and there are several columns I may wish to summarize by. So let's write a function for the summary, so I can easily vary the column to use for the .(var):

```
   baseballByCol <- function(col) {
       ddply(baseball, .(baseball[,col]), "nrow")
   }
```

This ALMOST works: `baseballByCol(2)` is identical to the output from `ddply(baseball, .(year), "nrow")` except for that `colnames(baseballByCol(2))` is `c("baseball[, col]", "nrow")` while `colnames(ddply(baseball, .(year), "nrow"))` is the desired `c("year", "nrow")`.

Of course we can solve that:

```
   baseballByCol <- function(col) {
       df <- ddply(baseball, .(baseball[,col]), "nrow")
       colnames(df)[1] <- colnames(baseball)[col]
       return(df)
   }
```

And now  `baseballByCol(2)` is completely identical to the output from `ddply(baseball, .(year), "nrow")`, to summarize by stint I can use `baseballByCol(3)` and so on.

But this smells a bit ugly. Is there really no better way to refer to the "by" variable by its column index rather than name, other than the `.(baseball[,col]), "nrow")` which messes up the column name?

And is there a cleaner solution in which the function takes the variable name as an argument rather than a column index?

Comment: You can just pass `col` directly, `ddply(baseball, col, 'nrow')` instead of using the `.()` syntax.

Comment: aha! how come `ddply(baseball, .(year), 'nrow')` and `ddply(baseball, 'year', 'nrow')` and `ddply(baseball, 2, 'nrow')` all produce the same output, but `ddply(baseball, .(2), 'nrow')` fails? It's dawning on me that it's presumably the same reason `ddply(baseball, .('year'), 'nrow')` fails - although I don't have a clear understanding of why that is, or what the .() syntax is for.

Comment: the `.()` syntax is special Hadley magic.  It works sorta like `attach` so you can use unqualified names in the function.  you can read more about it at `?"."` once you have the `plyr` package loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
baseballByCol <- function(col) {
    ddply(baseball, col, "nrow")
}
```

works with index and column name.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful and I had no idea from the documentation. Such a simple answer makes my question look dumb, but have just re-read `?ddply` and even in retrospect I wouldn't have guessed this from "`.variables` variables to split data frame by, as quoted variables, a formula or character vector". Is there any advice for a relative newbie so I can spot when a trick like this is possible from the documentation?

Comment: not really, sometimes the documentation **is** confusing. Looking at the examples in the function documentation usually helps, but not allways..

Comment: Many thanks. In fact in this case the function documentation was what confused me since the examples always used the .() syntax!